# How to stop JPA from creating an extra query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to fetch data from an endpoint, where I want to fetch all tasks that match the user id.
When I run my query on Postgres it runs like it's supposed to, but JPA for some reason also feels the necessity to fetch the user.
I need to fetch only the task, without fetching the user.
I've tried adding lazy loading, but it throws a serialization exception.
Any ideas how to make it not fetch extra data that I don't need?
I could work around this by creating a DTO, however, when accessing the database it will fetch unnecessary data and I'd like to avoid that.

My query looks like this:

`@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM tasks t WHERE t.user_id = :userId", nativeQuery = true) List<TaskEntity> findByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);`

My task entity:

```
public class TaskEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate date;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;

    // getters, setters and constructor 
}
```

My user entity:

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String password;
// getters, setters and constructor 
}
```

JPA is creating this query to fetch data:

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        tasks t 
    WHERE
        t.user_id = ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        u1_0.id,
        u1_0.email,
        u1_0.name,
        u1_0.password 
    from
        users u1_0 
    where
        u1_0.id=?
```

I dont have any extra logic yet, just calling the method.

```
controller
    @GetMapping("/user={id}")
public ResponseEntity<List<TaskEntity>> getTaskByUser(@PathVariable                                               Long id){
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.getTaskByUserId(id));
}

service
    public List<TaskEntity> getTaskByUserId(Long id){
    System.out.println("GET TASK BY USER ID");
    return repository.findByUserId(id);
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the `user_id` column is not a defined foreign key?  There's some threads that indicate if it's not a foreign key, this will break lazy fetching on ManyToOne.

Comment: Ideally the FetchType.LAZY should work for you. Are you sure you are not calling getUser() method of Task entity? Can you please share your POM file?

Comment: can you also share the method body where this query is invoked ?

Comment: Task is serializable - how are you serializing it? Make sure that your serialization method (ie JSON) isn't accessing the lazy relationship, or that you don't have other methods (equals, hashcode or anything else) inadvertently doing so either. You can try debugging to see where this query is being executed, as knowing that will help determine what can be done to stop it.

Comment: Managed to fix my problem. I had method getUser() inside of my taskEntity. After removing it hibernate is no longer fetching the extra data. 
I guess when TaskEntity was being constructed by jpa, it was automatically calling the getUser() and making an extra query to get the user data.

Comment: Glad you got it resolved, but I don't think it was JPA calling your getUser, not directly without there being a major bug - it had to be your own methods making the call or having that call in other accessors and methods JPA is required to call. This is especially common in hashcode/equals when the entity is used in Sets or Maps in other entities.

Answer (score 0):

You've set the user relationship in TaskEntity to lazy-load. But if anywhere in your code you access this user, it will trigger a database query for that user. Here's how to avoid it:

Don't Access the User: After fetching the task, make sure you're not calling getUser() or accessing the user directly. This causes Hibernate to fetch the user due to its lazy nature.

Use DTOs: Consider using DTOs. Map only needed fields from TaskEntity to the DTO without including the user. This way, even if you touch the user field in the logic layer, it won't query the database.

Try JPQL: Instead of native queries, use JPQL. It's better optimized for JPA. For example:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM TaskEntity t WHERE t.user.id = :userId")
List<TaskEntity> findByUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Handle Serialization: The error you saw can arise when lazy entities are serialized without being fully loaded. When serializing TaskEntity, make sure not to serialize the user too. If using Jackson, @JsonIgnore can help.

Bytecode Enhancement: A more advanced method, but you can use Hibernate's bytecode enhancement to refine lazy loading.

Avoid Open Session in View: Make sure not to use this pattern. It keeps the Hibernate session active for too long and can cause lazy entities to load unintentionally.

In short, ensure you're not accessing the user unintentionally after fetching the task. This way, Hibernate won't make extra user queries.

Comment: For some reason JPQL doesnt work, throws UnsatisfiedDependencyException.
OpenSessionInView did nothing for me.
@JsonIgnore is tricky, because i cant save my task properly if i use him, because i save my task with passing a userid.

I managed to fix this by making a query and mapping it directly to a TaskDTO, but i felt it was too complicaded for something that should be simple. 
So i dig a little more and found the problem, i had a getUser() method inside of my TaskEntity which i didnt really need, i removed it and it works perfectly now.

Your insights helped a lot, thanks.

Comment: did you use chatgpt or any similar AI at all to write any part of this answer?

Comment: @starball No, why? If my english feels off, its because im not a native speaker.